# Excel VBA plus =hyperlink()

Tags: excel, vba, function, hyperlink, scope

I'm attempting to write hyperlinks to cells via one button click from the ribbon in Excel 2007. These hyperlinks must, in turn, execute another routine that does stuff to the row on which they're located. However, the standard method of `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink()` will not work, as I need to execute this via an external xlam addin, and as far as I understand, this event triggers from hyperlink clicks located only in the same worksheet.

As a result, I have found that using the `=HYPERLINK("#funName()","Click me")` method works, but a problem exists that I am still experiencing.

The following is a trimmed down version of my already-working code:

```
Sub InsertLink() ' This is run directly by the callback for an IRibbonControl button click
  With Sheet1
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    While i <= lastrow
      Range("E" & i).Value = "=HYPERLINK(""#consolidateDuplicate(A" & i & ",C" & i & ")"",""Copy this row to next"")"
    Wend
    Call MsgBox ("Finished inserting hyperlinks on each row.", vbOKOnly)
  End With
End Sub

Sub consolidateDuplicate(PN, Quantity)
  Dim thisRow, prevQuant As Long
  thisRow = Selection.Row
  MsgBox("You clicked the hyperlink for " & thisRow & "Q: " & Quantity & ", PN: " & PN)
End Sub
```

Clicking the ribbon button successfully writes all hyperlinks into their respective rows as expected. However, when I try to click any of these hyperlinks, thus executing `consolidateDuplicate()` in the same add-in module, I immediately receive a "**Reference is not valid**" warning followed by the `MsgBox` message.

I have tried removing all code from the routine to no avail. I also tried the standard brute-force bypass method of adding `On Error Resume Next ... On Error Goto 0` as well as `Application.DisplayAlerts = False ... Application.DisplayAlerts = True`. Neither helps. I still receive the warning.

So while my script works fine and does what I want it to in the end, I feel like there should be a way to suppress the warning, or fix whatever is causing it, which I have a feeling, like `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink()`, is from storing the routine in the scope of an add-in module (required for my application), rather than keeping it totally contained in the calling workbook/sheet itself.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `consolidateDuplicate` subroutine should be a `Function`, returning the address that the hyperlink should take you to.  The lack of a return value is what is causing the "Reference is not valid" error.

The following code might work, effectively telling the hyperlink to take you to the cell in which the hyperlink was located:

```
Function consolidateDuplicate(PN, Quantity) As Range
    Dim thisRow, prevQuant As Long
    thisRow = Selection.Row
    MsgBox ("You clicked the hyperlink for " & thisRow & "Q: " & Quantity & ", PN: " & PN)
    Set consolidateDuplicate = Selection
End Function
```

Comment: Perfect! Originally I had this in there, yet for whatever reason I was seeing the same error. May have just been a typo which may account for why I removed it during my testing.